# How to detect a bottleneck in the system?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, performance

I run a Mathematica code which takes one hour to be finished. During this one hour the CPU never reaches the 100%. It reaches to 50% or around that. The CPU is Xeon e5-1650. Could it be that there is a bottleneck other than CPU. It is as if CPU can reach the 100% of being used but because it waits for something it cannot reach 100% of usage.

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

I think there is a bottleneck in the system other than CPU. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/775076/mathematica-benchmark-on-two-different-system) I asked about the `Mathematica` benchmark on two different systems, which one of them is the system I am addressing here.

### Edit

With regard to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/775076/mathematica-benchmark-on-two-different-system), I want to change the question to how I can detect the bottleneck in the system.

Comment: Because the process isn't doing enough instructions to cause it to be at 100%?

Comment: What system are you on? On Linux, top and htop give several metrics that help identifying the bottleneck.
For example, I have a server that gets high spikes of load, but doesn't use much CPU. I run top there during a spike and I saw "wa 85%" that means the bottleneck is in I/O.

Comment: @Bruno9779 I have Windows 7. How can I detect a bottleneck in Windows.

Comment: I can't help you there. Please put a tag with the OS next time.

Comment: @Ramhound. I cannot understand what you mean by "isn't doing enough instructions". The code solves a system of differential equation 5000 times.

Comment: According to http://ark.intel.com/products/64601/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-1650-12M-Cache-3_20-GHz-0_0-GTs-Intel-QPI this processor runs 12 threads. The program would have to be capable of splitting your problem down into at least 12 threads to reach 100% CPU usage. Look at the logical processor usage in Task Manager.